# PHP questions about inputs and checkboxes

Tags: php, html, input, checkbox

I have 2 questions:

1. what is the best way to fill an input in php (for example in asp.net: `textbox1.Text = "hello";`), I tried `<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?> ">` and then in my php script: `$name = $myObj['name'];`. Is there any other way?
2. How can I uncheck a checkbox in php and not by renedering the whole checkbox input?

Thanks a lot

Comment: turn off register_globals :)

Comment: @RoyalBg Maybe you should go on to explain why this is relevant.

Comment: @RoyalBg what is this and why?

Comment: With PHP you can output HTML (i.e. text). Just output the HTML that produces the checkboxen you want. Nothing special about it. The ASP.NET `textbox1.Text = "hello"` is just a super high-level framework abstraction which does the same thing in the end.

Comment: `.net` is a framework, `php` is a language. There are php frameworks that can make form controls more convenient for you, but at the base it's all the same: create the input as you describe (be sure to use `htmlspecialchars()` where appropriate), and examine the `$_POST` or `$_GET` array on submit).

Comment: It was about 1. where `$name` is going to be globally recieved from `$_POST['name']`, because of register_globals. Once you post the text box with name `name` with value of the `$name`, you are putting this value to `$_POST['name']`, so `$_POST['name'] = $name`, but globalising the post array results in `$name = $name`. Register globals is a directive in your php config. http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name?>">
```

To check the boxes, use:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1" <?php if($condition==true)echo "checked"?>>
```

Comment: `value="<?php echo $name?>"` is dangerous - it may break input code.

Comment: @FlashThunder what is a better way?

Comment: @FlashThunder if register_globals are disabled, and $name is not comming from the user, it's all ok

Comment: The way is good, but name needs some preprocessing... like `addslashes()`

Comment: yes $name should not contain " in it. then reflect all html code

Answer (score -1):

**if you want to check any checkbox if condition is satisfied the use:**
 `

```
$i = 1;
<input type="checkbox" name="name-field" value="something" <?php if($i== 1){ echo "checked"; } ?> />
?>
```